# Is there a straightforward 16bit microcontroller?

Tags: microcontroller

Background

Some of my sketches or ideas require a common data buss to all perph chips.

The issue

This way issue still lays before me, how then, if I am going for a common data buss. how do I address each chip via this microcontroller?

However, Using a microprocessor is a plus in that direction, but i rather not design something that takes more chips when i can  just handle with one central chip to work out the calculations and decisions.

Main idea

My question is. What is a good microcontroller that offers me

- 16 bit parallel ports.
- easy adressing to perph chips
- able to handle a wide variety of brands.

Documents and data sheets that are related

Here are some related documents that I intended to use.

- 8bit Atmel Atmega640 microcontroller
- HS cmos ARING bus interface 16bit
- AD5207 2 channel 256 position digital potentiometer
- RIRWE416D4 series 4M high speed SRAM 256kbit × 16 bit

Finding a good microcontroller will be a step into finding a good 16 ADC.

Why this question

The intersil 80cxx platform is cringe worthy in my view because, the address and the data is share a common pin set and I need extra hardware to demux the data and the address. Also,  the platform they give is byte oriented I need word.

Replacement requirements.

I need something that gives me good high speed performance that I can use in a microcomputer esk layout.

My number one priority is finding something that is highly customizable with the requirement that I can use the standard 15 pin serial com ports or at least

The parallax propellor 8 core is close could go down to two core.

Comment: how about a Parallax Propeller?  ... it is an 8 core microcontroller ... https://www.parallax.com/product/p8x32a-q44

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The propeller core is flexible to allow 16 bit ports and SPI, I2C or any data buss nterfacing protocol. Without the need for interrupts.